# How do i apply css to a actionlink in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, fonts

Below is my html link
`<a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i> Dashboard</a>`

How do i convert the above to the below action link with CSS (`<i>` tag)
`@Html.ActionLink("AppStore", "Index", "Home")`

Please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have html tag inside `anchor` tag use `Url.Action` instead

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home") "><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i>Dashboard</a>
```

[Correct overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) for `Html.Actionlink` is

```
//linkText, actionName, controllerName, routeValues, htmlAttributes
@Html.ActionLink("AppStore", "Index", "Home", new object{}, new {class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"})
```

Comment: If that helped and solved ur issue, please accept it as answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this

@Html.ActionLink("Name", "viewname", "Controllername", new {HTML Attributes here})

```
@Html.ActionLink("AppStore", "Index", "Home", new {@class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"})
```

Comment: It is valid overload?

Comment: @NitinVarpe yes its a valid overload check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink%28v=vs.118%29.aspx

Comment: Overload number please?

Comment: I already tried it its not working it needs the css declaration needs the <i> tag

Answer (score 0):

The following function tells you how to add css in your action link call.

```
@Html.Action("AppStore", "Index", "Home", New With {.class="cssvalue"})
```

The above syntax is `vb.net`

Comment: It is valid overload?

Comment: no is isnt,please check link in my answer for correct overload

Answer (score 0):

```
       @Html.ActionLink("AppStore", "Index", "Home", new {ProductID = 73}, new {@class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"})
```

You have asked a question about which overload to choose .When you start the paranthesis "(" after @HTML.ActionLink you can scroll with the up and down arrow to see which overload works best for you .In case you would like to specify the productID etc ,you can do so by using the above code.